# Array giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS in for loop

Tags: objective-c, iphone, arrays, ios4, exc-bad-access

I have a C array defined in my method as:

```
int c = 4;
int r = 5;
keysArray[c][r];
```

I have this for loop, which works, populating the `keysArray` as expected.

```
for (int row = 0; row < r; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < c; column++){
        keysArray[column][row] = [anotherArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"array1 %@",keysArray[column][row]);
        [anotherArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

Then in a for loop underneath, featuring exactly the same looping counter structure, when i try to NSLog the array, it gives an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
for (int row = 0; row < r; row++){
    for (int column = 0; column < c; column++) {            
        NSLog(@"array2: %@",keysArray[column][row]); //EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
    }
}
```

What would cause this to happen, given that the keysArray is defined in the method body, outside of both sets of loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retain the objects held in your C array.  Unlikes an NS*Array, a C array does not retain on adding to the array.

However, for a no-holes 2D array like that, I'd just use a single NSMutableArray.   Any N-dimensional array can be represented as a line--  as a one dimensional array-- with simple math.

Namely, to determine the index of an object at (X,Y), use `(Y * width) + X)`.

The only caveat is that `NS*Array` does not support "holes".  You will need to fill the array row by row.  That is, for a 3x4 (3 wide, 4 tall) array, you would fill it in the order `0,0`, `1,0`, `2,0`, `0,1`, `1,1`, etc...

Obviously, `insert` and `remove` operations will mess up your 2D representation (but they would in an `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableArrays`, too).

Alternatively, use `NSPointerArray` as it can have holes.

Answer (score 1):

Are the contents of `anotherArray` retained by some other object? If not, they do not exist anymore in the second loop. WTH are you using a C array to store Objective-C objects anyway?

```
int c = 4;
int r = 5;
NSMutableArray *keysArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:c];

for (int column = 0; column < c; column++) {
    [keysArray addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:r]];
    for (int row = 0; row < r; row++) {
        [[keysArray objectAtIndex:column] addObject:[anotherArray objectAtIndex:0]];
        [anotherArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
}

for (int row = 0; row < r; row++){
    for (int column = 0; column < c; column++) {            
        NSLog(@"array2: %@", [[keysArray objectAtIndex:column] objectAtIndex:row]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need a multidimensional array to store row/column positions of buttons in a grid, using a C array was the simplest way i could think of, unless you could suggest a more appropriate method? Why should it matter if anotherArray is retained elsewhere, aren't its contents stored in keysArray now anyway? The anotherArray is an ivar.

Comment: It's not about `anotherArray` being retained, it's about its contents. By removing them from the array, they are being released. If you are not retaining them elsewhere, they will be deallocated. A two-dimensional array is just an array of arrays. You can easily accomplish that with `NSMutableArrays`, too: `[[columns objectAtIndex:column] objectAtIndex:row];`

Comment: OK i have implemented it using objective c arrays now, but still failing at this point. Does storing them in the mutable array not retain them?

Comment: Which array would i access in the second loop, using your example?

Comment: I get this error when i try your idea: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`

Comment: That's right, there was an error in the code. I'm typing this without testing, why don't you engage the debugger and go through it yourself. This isn't rocket science.

Comment: I appreciate your help for this, this problem has been bugging me for ages and i'm just getting tangled up. Its still EXC_BAD_ACCESS'ing on the second time the method is called. I think the problem is like you first said about the objects being released, but anotherArray is an instance variable and i tried `retain`'ing the value when its added, but it still crashes... Where would be the best place to retain the array?

Answer (score 0):

Could this be the problem :

```
[anotherArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
keysArray[column][row] = [[anotherArray objectAtIndex:0] retain];
```

although if I were you I would use NSMutableArray of NSMutableArray instead

Comment: I would create a new class to wrap the C array

Comment: @JeremyP yes that would be even better.